# AudioToolBox in Swift - Sound works in Simulator but not on my IPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, audio, audiotoolbox

I'm creating a music app where different chimes will be played at different points in a rhythm cycle. So far, my code works fine in the Simulator but I'm not getting any sound on my device. I get sounds from other apps. Is there something wrong with my code? Thanks for you help!

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

func playChime1() {
    var chime1URL: NSURL?
    var chime1ID:SystemSoundID = 0
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chime", ofType: "mp3")
    chime1URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(chime1URL!, &chime1ID)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(chime1ID)
}
func playChime2() {
    var chime2URL: NSURL?
    var chime2ID:SystemSoundID = 0
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chime2", ofType: "mp3")
    chime2URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(chime2URL!, &chime2ID)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(chime2ID)
}
func playChime3() {
    var chime3URL: NSURL?
    var chime3ID:SystemSoundID = 0
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chime3", ofType: "mp3")
    chime3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(chime3URL!, &chime3ID)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(chime3ID)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and realised my iPhone was on silent mode, taking it off silent played the sounds.

Unfortunately AudioToolbox sounds respond to the 'Ringer' volume of the device, and not the 'Volume' setting that audio through AVFoundation uses.

It makes sense, as AudioToolbox is supposed to be used for system sounds.

Answer (score 0):

From related question: [AudioServicesPlaySystemSound not working on iPad device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036498/audioservicesplaysystemsound-not-working-on-ipad-device?rq=1)

You can't play MP3 on iDevice, need to use a different framework.

Comment: The device isn't muted, volume is all the way up, but still no sound.

Comment: The call `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` returns an `OSStatus` code - have you checked that?

Comment: I haven't...How would I go about checking that? Also, why would sound work on the simulator, but not on the device?

Comment: `let errorCode = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(chime3URL, &chime3ID); print(errorCode)`

Comment: It returns a "0"... I believe that means no Error, any suggestions what might be wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Answer changed, found the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the number of buffers allocated for AudioQueue, I allocated 3 and it worked on MacOS, however for iOS device you need at least 4